# Google Cloud Shell has been stuck on "Provisioning your Cloud Shell machine" for hours now

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google cloud and I am trying to sue the cloud shell. After going to the page with it it just has been saying "Provisioning your Cloud Shell machine" for hours now with no activity or prompts. Am I doing something wrong here or is this just the time it takes to generate the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Starting Cloud Shell takes only a minute or two. What region are you in? Which browser? Do you have a firewall or blocker running? Start over and try again. You have provided no details from which we can help you.

Comment: There is an [issue](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/support/21001) with Cloud SDK Versions 321, 322 and 323 Installed on Windows. what is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart it. Click on the 3 dots on the right of the window and hit restart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update, after switching from un googled chromium to Firefox it cleared up the issue, I am guessing some block that was causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox stays in this state forever, for me.
Microsoft Edge works just fine..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome or an incognito tab then the following solves the issue:
At the right hand side of your search bar just ensure that Third-party cookie blocking is turned off to allow cookies.

The location of the Third-party cookie blocking icon:

[image: Screenshot showing the location of the Third-party cookie blocking icon]

Answer (score 0):

Used Chrome instead of Firefox solved the issue.